# Firebase Storage, trying to download bytes, task never finishes nor triggers any errors

Tags: unity, storage, firebase

Firebase Storage's GetBytesAsync never finishes or changes status.

```
[ConsoleCommand("test-storage")]
public static void TestDownload() {
    var storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    StorageReference pathReference = storage.GetReference("test.txt");

    const long maxAllowedSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    pathReference.GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogException(task.Exception);
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] fileContents = task.Result;
            Debug.Log("Finished downloading!");
        }
    });
}
```

this is literally the code from the firebase storage documentation.I also tried using a coroutine to wait for the task to either fail or finish. that task's status is constantly "WaitingForActivation".
I've copied the exact code from the video tutorial on firebase storage as well as the one from the documentation. Neither yields any result for the task.

Comment: Waiting for activation sounds more like a credentials problem or chosen model of your firebase instance

Comment: @Zibelas is there any way I can get any output on what the problem is? in their tutorials there's supposed to be an "exception" property, which would return the error. but since the task never gets to a finish, it doesn't return any errors.